# SqlAlchemy how to query column A==a and B==b and A==b and B==a

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a table that have `enemy_one`, `fight_id` and `enemy_two`.

The thing is, sometimes `enemy_two` becomes `enemy_one` and vice versa.

I can do:

```
session.query(Fight.fight_id).filter(Fight.enemy_one=='Jack', Fight.enemy_two=='Fat Chinese').all()
```

then:

```
session.query(Fight.fight_id).filter(Fight.enemy_one=='Fat Chinese', Fight.enemy_two=='Jack').all()
```

And this way I get all the fights, but there's a way, to bind this two query's together?

Comment: If you did not denormalize your data model, you'd have a table with `fight_id` and `enemy_id`, for any number of enemies. Then you could just check that you have records for both enemies for a given `fight_id`. Just saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `in_` clause:

```
def get_fights(enemy_one, enemy_two):
    return (
        session
        .query(Fight)
        .filter(Fight.enemy_one.in_([enemy_one, enemy_two]))
        .filter(Fight.enemy_two.in_([enemy_one, enemy_two]))
        .filter(Fight.enemy_one != Fight_enemy_two)
    )
```

With the `or_` clause:

```
def get_fights(enemy_one, enemy_two):
    return (
        session
        .query(Fight)
        .filter(or_(
            and_(Fight.enemy_one == enemy_one, Fight.enemy_two == enemy_two),
            and_(Fight.enemy_one == enemy_two, Fight.enemy_two == enemy_one),
        ))
    )
```

Comment: I stick with `or_` because make more sense to me. Thanks a lot for your precious help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to use sqlalchemy's function `or_()` with the filter operator `in_` like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import or_

enemies = ['Fat Chinese', 'Jack']

session.query(Fight.fight_id).filter(
    or_(
        Fight.enemy_one.in_(enemies),
        Fight.enemy_two.in_(enemies)
       )).all()
```

Comment: That's not quite the same expression. It will include `Fight`s that has *either* enemy as `Fat Chinese` or `Jack`, not just the `Fight`s that has *both*, but in either order.

Comment: `session.query(Fight.fight_id).filter(Fight.enemy_one.in_(enemies), Fight.enemy_two.in_(enemies)).all()` This seems to do the right thing, or Am I missing something? @wanderlust I Intend to get a list where only those 2 fight each other, but your `in_`is the key ;)

Comment: This query will also give you results when `enemy_one` and `enemy_two` are the same. I'd personally write this as two `and_`s which check equality rather than use `in_` enclosed in an `or_`, but also have a check constraint that `enemy_one` and `enemy_two` can't be the same, assuming that would be a pointless case for your application.

Comment: @adarsh something like this: `session.query(Fight).filter(and_(Fight.enemy_one=='Jack'),(Fight.enemy_two=='Fat Chinese'))or_(and_(Fight.enemy_one=='Fat Chinese'),(Fight.enemy_two=='Jack')).all()` but not working cause I don't know how to puzzle this right